# Get Image name from full image path using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I am trying to display an image with a caption and thumbnails. I am able to display the picture but I am finding difficult to display the image file name as caption.

Below is my code:

```
<?php
$files = glob("images/Friends/*.*");
for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++)
{
    $num = $files[$i]; 
    echo '<div class="w3-content" style="max-width:800px;position:relative;padding-top:0px;">';
    echo '<div class="w3-display-container mySlides">';
    echo '<div class="col s12 m6 l12">';
    echo '<div class="page4">';
    echo '<img src="'.$num.'" height="750" width="780" alt="random image" class="responsive-img" >'."&nbsp;&nbsp;";    
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<a class="w3-btn-floating w3-hover-dark-grey"    style="position:absolute;top:45%;left:0" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">❮</a>';
    echo '<a class="w3-btn-floating w3-hover-dark-grey" style="position:absolute;top:45%;right:0" onclick="plusDivs(1)">❯</a>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo ' </div>';
}
?>  

<script>
    var slideIndex = 1;
    showDivs(slideIndex);
    function plusDivs(n) {
        showDivs(slideIndex += n);
    }
    function showDivs(n) {
        var i;
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
        if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
        if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show caption set title attribute. And set name of image in tile attribute.

To get Image name from fullpath of Image use `basename($num)`

Please replace your php code with below.

```
echo '<img src="'.$num.'" height="750" width="780" alt="'.basename($num).'" title="'.basename($num).'" class="responsive-img" >'."&nbsp;&nbsp;";
```

To get filename without extension for every image place below code in loop. And place `$filename` variable where you want to display image name.

```
$filenamewithextension = basename($num);
$fileextenstion = pathinfo($filenamewithextension, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$filename = basename($num,$fileextenstion);
$filename = trim(preg_replace('/[0-9]+/', '', $filename));
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. It's still not displaying but one change and its that I could see the image file name when i move the mouse point over the image.

Comment: After which change you are able to get the file caption on mouse over? As per my knowledge to get the caption title should be set of HTML attribute and as such you want to display image name in caption name of image set in the title attribute.

Comment: after adding this- alt="'.basename($num).'" title="'.basename($num).'". Its displaying on mouseover

Comment: I cannot set it in HTML as the images are already in the folder and of every image, I want only its filename to be displayed

Comment: Ok so this is what you want right? You want to display the caption with image name on hover of image..

Comment: Hey there is no as such caption separately. Its just that every image file is named something like(for example) my first snow experience.jpg, my first day of university.jpg and now I want only my first snow experience and my first day of university to be displayed as captions for respective images. Not on hover but along with image as its displayed

Comment: Ok so you want filename without extension to display it in the HTML. Right?

Comment: Yes for every respective images its respective filenames

Comment: Ok I got your concern. Please check my updated answer. You will be able to get image name without extension for every image in the loop and you can place the image name where you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124637/discussion-between-heblev-and-rahul-patel).